# After successfully creating a MySQL database within Eclipse Juno, how/where do I save my database?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, eclipse-dtp

I'm in the Database Perspective, and being that this is the first time for me working with the any type of database within Eclipse, I want to make sure I save it correctly upon exit. When I click Save As, it prompts me to select a folder, but nothing jumps out at me as saying "Database Project".

Or, can I save inside of my Dynamic Web Project Folder I already have, as that is it is a JSP project that will be working with this database?

Comment: What do You  want to do? Save data in DB or save Database Perspective? Please explain it and try improve(learn) your java knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got it. Once the MySQL database is built, as long as everything is committed (set to Auto Commit), on my Tomcat Server it will stay there.

In other words, I can turn off my Server, exit Eclipse, come back in, and all tables are there as I left them.

So, in sum...nothing special needs to be done to retain the database.